# How can i load part of code? PHP

Tags: php, require, implode

how can i load a part of code? Something like that:

```
require('script.php',0,40); // require(filename,start_line,end_line)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: You can't do that in PHP, why don't you just put the code into a separate file and include that

Comment: Why dont you make a function and call it

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible. Just divide the file into multiple files. Also if it was possible it would be hard to maintain